Why is HTMX's hx-post on a form element causing a Mixed Content Error?
I'm new to web development, so it's very possible I'm missing something quite obvious here, thank you to anyone for any help.
I'm encountering a Mixed Content error in Chrome when I use hx-post on a form, even when I specify the url to contain https or give the _scheme to the url_for Flask function.
I'm trying to make a simple webpage that allows a user to download an input template, upload the completed template, run a script on the input, and then download the resulting file.
I'm using Flask, the server is Gunicorn, and it's hosted on Azure Web App Services.
Full webpage HTML:
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>My app</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
  <script src="static/bootstrap/htmx/htmx.2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/bootstrap/htmx/hyperscript.min.js"></script>
</head>

<html>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="px-4 py-3 my-2 text-center">
      <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/image.jpg') }}"
        alt="Logo" width="384" height="192" />
      <h1 class="display-6 fw-bold text-primary">Welcome to The App</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="px-4 py-3 my-2 text-center">
      <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('template_download') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <label for="name" class="form-label fw-bold fs-3">1. Download the Input Template</label>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center my-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 gap-3">Download</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="px-4 py-3 my-2 text-center">
      <form hx-encoding='multipart/form-data' hx-post="/input_upload">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <label for="input_file" class="form-label fw-bold fs-3">2. Select the Completed Input File</label>
          <p><input type='file' name='input_file'></p>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center my-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 gap-3">
              Upload
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>

The specific section causing the issue:

   <div class="px-4 py-3 my-2 text-center">
      <form hx-encoding='multipart/form-data' hx-post="/input_upload">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <label for="input_file" class="form-label fw-bold fs-3">2. Select the Completed Input File</label>
          <p><input type='file' name='input_file'></p>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center my-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 gap-3">
              Upload
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>


I've also tried "{{ url_for('input_upload', _scheme='https', _external=True) }}" in the hx-post field, and the explicit full https url to the page. All produce the Mixed Content error.
I've also tried it without HTMX, and get a 400 error which I don't understand:
    <div class="px-4 py-3 my-2 text-center">
      <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('input_upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <label for="file" class="form-label fw-bold fs-3">2. Select the Completed Input File</label>
          <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center my-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 gap-3">Upload</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

When I inspect the page after attempting an upload, I see the full https url in the hx-post field when using url_for, but the Mixed Content error message shows http:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<my_website_name>/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://<my_website_name>/input_upload'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I don't understand what's causing this, so any help is really appreciated.
P.S. here is the app.py for the website as well:
import os
import logging
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    send_from_directory,
    url_for,
)


# Sets logging level to DEBUG.
logging.basicConfig(filename="record.log", level=logging.DEBUG)

# Start and configure the Flask app.
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH"] = 1024 * 1024 * 10  # 10 MB limit
app.config["UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS"] = [".xlsx", ".xlsm"]
app.config["UPLOAD_PATH"] = "uploads"
app.config["PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME"] = "https"


# Filesize validation. Automatically detected by Flask based on the configuration.
@app.errorhandler(413)
def too_large(e):
    return "File is too large", 413


def allowed_file(filename):
    return (
        "." in filename
        and filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1].lower() in app.config["UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS"]
    )


# App Page Routing.
@app.route("/")
def index():
    app.logger.debug("Request for index page received")
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/favicon.ico")
def favicon():
    app.logger.debug("Request for favicon received")
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.join(app.root_path, "static"),
        "favicon.ico",
        mimetype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
    )


@app.route("/template_download", methods=["POST"])
def template_download():
    app.logger.debug("Request for template download received")
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.join(app.root_path, "static"),
        "<filename>.xlsm",
        mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12",
    )


@app.route("/input_upload", methods=["POST"])
def input_upload():
    app.logger.debug("Request for input upload received")
    if request.files:
        input_file = request.files["input_file"]
        if input_file.filename == "":
            app.logger.debug("No file selected")
            return redirect(request.url)
        else:
            if allowed_file(input_file.filename):
                # Gets the username from the email address in header.
                name = request.headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"].split("@")[0]
                # Creates a folder for the user if it doesn't exist.
                os.makedirs(
                    os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_PATH"], name), exist_ok=True
                )
                # Saves the file to the user's folder. Always overwrites prior input.
                input_file.save(
                    os.path.join(
                        app.config["UPLOAD_PATH"], name, "input.xlsx"
                    )  # Always save as .xlsx.
                )
                app.logger.debug(f"User {name} input saved")
                return redirect(request.url)
            else:
                app.logger.debug("File type not allowed")
                return redirect(request.url)


@app.route("/output_download", methods=["POST"])
def output_download():
    app.logger.debug("Request for output download received")
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        # debug=True,
    )


The Mixed Content error occurs when a resource loaded over HTTPS tries to make a request over HTTP.

I tried your code and deployed to the Azure web app without any issues.
The Mixed Content error is due to a conflict between HTTP and HTTPS requests on a site served over HTTPS.

It is better to use Azure Blob Storage to store uploaded files because it provides long term storage and easy to access.
If your using basic or standard App service plan try to upgrade it to premium.
Make sure to enable Https only in configuration section of Azure Web app.


I made small changes in your app. py then it worked fine for me.
app.config["UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS"] = ["xlsx", "xlsm"]


@app.route("/input_upload", methods=["POST"])
def input_upload():
    app.logger.debug("Request for input upload received")
    if 'input_file' not in request.files:
        app.logger.debug("No file part in the request")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    input_file = request.files["input_file"]
    if input_file.filename == "":
        app.logger.debug("No file selected")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if allowed_file(input_file.filename):
        name = request.headers.get("X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME", "default_user").split("@")[0]
        user_folder = os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_PATH"], name)
        os.makedirs(user_folder, exist_ok=True)
        save_path = os.path.join(user_folder, "input.xlsx")
        input_file.save(save_path)
        app.logger.debug(f"User {name} input saved at {save_path}")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        app.logger.debug("File type not allowed")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

Below is my complete code of app. py:
import os
import logging
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, send_from_directory, url_for
logging.basicConfig(filename="record.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH"] = 1024 * 1024 * 10  # 10 MB limit
app.config["UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS"] = ["xlsx", "xlsm"]
app.config["UPLOAD_PATH"] = "uploads"
app.config["PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME"] = "https"
@app.errorhandler(413)
def too_large(e):
    return "File is too large", 413
def allowed_file(filename):
    return (
        "." in filename
        and filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1].lower() in app.config["UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS"]
    )
@app.route("/")
def index():
    app.logger.debug("Request for index page received")
    return render_template("index.html")
@app.route("/favicon.ico")
def favicon():
    app.logger.debug("Request for favicon received")
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.join(app.root_path, "static"),
        "favicon.ico",
        mimetype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
    )
@app.route("/template_download", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def template_download():

    app.logger.debug("Request for template download received")
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.join(app.root_path, "static"),
        "template.xlsm",  # Replace with your actual file name
        mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12",
        as_attachment=True
    )
@app.route("/input_upload", methods=["POST"])
def input_upload():
    app.logger.debug("Request for input upload received")
    if 'input_file' not in request.files:
        app.logger.debug("No file part in the request")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    input_file = request.files["input_file"]
    if input_file.filename == "":
        app.logger.debug("No file selected")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if allowed_file(input_file.filename):
        name = request.headers.get("X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME", "default_user").split("@")[0]
        user_folder = os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_PATH"], name)
        os.makedirs(user_folder, exist_ok=True)
        save_path = os.path.join(user_folder, "input.xlsx")
        input_file.save(save_path)
        app.logger.debug(f"User {name} input saved at {save_path}")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        app.logger.debug("File type not allowed")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
@app.route("/output_download", methods=["POST"])
def output_download():
    app.logger.debug("Request for output download received")
    pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Azure App service Output:


This was it, thank you Aslesha!
I just needed to set the configuration to "https only".
